# Looping through a page until certain movie found

Tags: javascript, loops, web-scraping, while-loop

I created a while loop that will keep scraping a page for a certain movie until it is found, this is an external module/helper by the way, but for some reason it doesn't work, this function is later called in order to get the data result from **result** and then grab the item in the result array the result will also have name of the movie and price:

```
const movies = "AVENGERS END GAME;

module.exports = {

    spider: function () {

        var target = 2
        const extractmovies = document.querySelectorAll('some.selector1')

        let result = [];
        let targetss = [];
        var movie_Name, movie_Price

        var i = 0;
        while (result <= 2) {
            for ( extract of extractmovies) {

                const nameChk = extract.querySelector('selector')
                    item_Name = nameChk.innerText

                const priceChk = extract.querySelector('g.iu')
                    item_Price = parseInt(priceChk.getAttribute('ggfg')) 

                result.push({
                    Name: item_Name,
                    Price: item_Price,
                })
            }

            for (myTarget of result) {
                if (myTarget.Name == keywords) {
                    targetss.push(1)
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        return targetss;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess for `while (result <= 2)` part you wanted to have `while (result.length <= 2)`. It's an array which has a `length` property.

Comment: oh snap i dint didnt see that, i will give it a try and get back to you

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your `while` loop. Technically variable `result` is an array which has a `length` property. So I would change the line from `while (result <= 2)` to `while (result.length <= 2)`.

Read further here: [Array.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

I hope this helps!